# Excel: Find doesn't find it

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

In my spreadsheet, there are three 2,280,000. One of them is a calculated value, 19000*120, the other two are plain numbers.

When I used the Find/Replace function to find 2280000 by formulas, it only found the two plain numbers. It found nothing by values. The calculated number was not found by either method.

Any explanation why the calculated number is not found and nothing is found by values?

Answer (score 2):

I've made an experiment and my conclusion is that it's related to the formating of the numbers in the cells. Notice that my search found both the value generated by formula and the one in plain text when they were formated (comma separated) like the one in the search box:

[image: Search in excell]

The result of the formula without comma (2280000) was not found by the search even though it is the result of the same formula (=19000*120). From that I would say the search is "Format" sensitive.

Comment: In a new workbook, I put in 2,280,000, 2280000, and =19000*120. For some reason, this time Find found all of them. Don't know what the problem was before. There is certainly something peculiar with that particular workbook in which Find did not work.

Comment: I would have guessed a floating point error preventing an exact match.  But I think you hit it.  I believe find/replace treats cell contents as text strings based on how they're formatted to appear.